# Find UPPERCASE names that end with a colon

Tags: regex, notepad++

Find UPPERCASE names that start with either a letter or digits.
Could include digits, hyphens, periods and spaces with colon at end of name.

```
MR. SMITH:
- CAPTAIN AMERICA:
ANT-MAN:
2014 NEBULA:
-2012 IRON MAN:
BOY 1:

1
00:00:07,174 --> 00:00:09,837
BARTON: Okay, hold on.

16
00:00:36,411 --> 00:00:37,527
- COOPER: Nice!
- LAURA: Nice throw, kiddo.
```

Here is my best attempt, but it is also selecting parts of the timecodes.
It's also not filling groups correctly.

Find: `([A-Z0-9])(?:([A-Z0-9\.\-\s]*)*\:+)`

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/w1cf5W/5)

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern: `([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9. -]+)(?=:\B)`

See Regex101 [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OwLhhC/1)

Comment: The dim light is getting brighter,  Just what I needed, thank you Alireza.